# Adding values large digits

Tags: java, list, linked-list, double

I am constructing objects with large integers and adding them together. Problem being, I don't know how to exactly code it. I construct a object with value 123456789, then I construct a second object by deep copy method with value 123456789. I have to traverse through and add each digit from the least significant digit to the most significant digit. This is my code logically to me. 
I've already created one bigNumber 123456789, I have to deep copy it which I've done. Then I have to add the two bigNumber's together

```
This is my main method

public static void main(String[] args) {
BigNumber b1 = new BigNumber();
   for (int i=9; i>=1; i--)
   {
       b1.addDigit(i);
   }
   System.out.println("b1 is " + b1.toString()); //return 123456789; corrent

BigNumber b2 = new BigNumber(b1); //Creates a deep copy of b1 123456789
System.out.println("b2: " + b2.toString()); //return 123456789
System.out.println(b1.add(b2).toString()); //should return 123456789 + 123456789 = 246913578
}
```

This is my add method

```
public BigNumber add(BigNumber otherNum)
{

        BigNumber newNum = new BigNumber(); // Create the new Number
        BigNumber secNum = new BigNumber(); //
        DigitNode temp = head;
        while (temp != null) { //while loop to set the numbers 123456789
            secNum.addDigit(temp.getDigit());
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        //At this I'm lost. I need to somehow get b1.. then get add it to my secNum that I made to 123456789, and put that into newNum and return it..
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may deal with them as Strings .
However , you should take care of lots of things I wrote as comments :

```
public class LongIntegersAritymetic {

// MAKE SURE TO CHECK THE SIGNS OF BOTH NUMBERS
// 4 SITUATIONS:
/* num1 + and num2 + =====> add
 * num1 + and num2 - =====> remove the sign from num2
 * and call substract(num1, num2_without_sign)
 * num1 - and num2 + =====> remove the sign from num1
 * and call substract(num2, num1_without_sign)
 * num1 - and num2 - =====> remove the sign from num1 and num2
 * and call add(num1_without_sing, num2_without_sign)
 * finally add the - sign to result*/


private static boolean changeResultSign = false;



public static String add(String num1, String num2) {

   String result = "";

   int n1 = 0, n2 = 0, res = 0, minLength = 0, carry = 0, maxLength = 0;

   if(num1 != null & num2 != null) {
           // num1 + and num2 + =====> add default
       // num1 - and num2 - =====> remove the sign from num1 || solved! 
       ////and call add(num1_without_sing, num2_without_sign) || solved!
       if(num1.charAt(0) == '-' & num2.charAt(0)== '-'){
           num1 = num1.substring(1);
           num2 = num2.substring(1);
           changeResultSign  = true;
       }
       // num1 - and num2 + =====> remove the sign from num1 || solved!
       //and call add(num1_without_sing, num2) || solved!
   else if(num1.charAt(0)=='-'){
       num1 = num1.substring(1);
       String a = subtarct(num2,num1);
       return a;
   }
   // num1 + and num2 - =====> remove the sign from num2 ||solved!
   //and call substract(num1, num2_without_sign) ||solved!
   else if(num2.charAt(0)=='-'){
       num2 = num2.substring(1);
       String b = subtarct(num1,num2);
       return b;
   }
  if(checkDigits(num1) & checkDigits(num2)) {
     minLength = Math.min(num1.length(), num2.length());
     maxLength = Math.max(num1.length(), num2.length());
     for(int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
       n1 = num1.charAt(num1.length()-1-i) - '0';
       n2 = num2.charAt(num2.length()-1-i) - '0';
       res = (n1 + n2 + carry) % 10 ;
       carry = (n1 + n2 + carry) / 10;
       // (new Integer(res)).toString();
       result = res + result ;  // CHECK THE VALIDITY OF THIS!!!
     }
     for(int i = minLength; i < maxLength; i++) {
        if(num1.length() >  num2.length()) {
           n1 = num1.charAt(num1.length()-1-i) - '0';
           res = (n1 + carry) % 10 ;
           carry = (n1 + carry) / 10;
           result =res + result ; // CHECK THE VALIDITY OF THIS!!!
        }
        else {
           n2 = num2.charAt(num2.length()-1-i) - '0';
           res = (n2 + carry) % 10 ;
           carry = (n2 + carry) / 10;
           result = res+ result ; // CHECK THE VALIDITY OF THIS!!!
        }
      }
      if(carry == 1)
        result = carry +result ; // CHECK THE VALIDITY OF THIS!!!
   } // End of if for valid digit Strings
   else
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid numbers!");
   }
   else
     throw new NullPointerException("Missing number(s)!");
return result ;
}



public static boolean checkDigits(String num) {
   boolean a = true;
    if(num != null) {
      for(int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
         if(num.charAt(i) < '0' | num.charAt(i) > '9')
             a = false;

      }
      return a;  }
   else
     throw new NullPointerException("Missing number(s)!");
  }



public static void main (String[] args){
    System.out.print(add("8437598745","8437598745"));
}}
```

Comment: Is this the general idea of things?